# Windows application and Spy++

Tags: c#, c, windows, winforms, winapi

I am unable to figure out why I can use Spy++ to get handle, window class etc of some windows application. For example, iexplore.exe, it just doesn't work on url text box or any text, edit box area if any in the page loaded; there are also windows application I get only the outer layer's properties whereas its internal buttons, textbox or combox are inaccessible. In these applications what should I do to reach them ? Thank you :)

Comment: Crystal ball says: "use the 64-bit version of Spy++".

Comment: @Hans: Spy++ works fine across 63/32bit boundaries for pretty much anything HWND-tree related. (Not sure of events offhand since those require hooks, but all the win32 tree and property APIs work just fine regardless of the 'bitness' of the target HWND.) Issue here is that there's no HWNDs specifically for those child UI elements in the first place

Answer (score 4):

These programs use windowless controls.

Instead of using standard Windows controls, they draw and process everything themselves within one giant container.

Comment: This is correct. You are probably interested in the window handles so that you can automate. Use UIAutomation for that.

Comment: Agree. You can also walk the child window hierarchy using GetWindow.

Comment: @kol: No, you can't.  Windowless controls aren't child window hierarchy

Comment: @SLaks Oh, I see. Thanks. -- Anyway, I know for sure that the rendering control of IE is a child window, and embedded Flash, Silverlight and Java Applet objects are child windows, too.

Comment: @kol and you should use EnumChildWindows anyway.

Comment: @Kol - "embedded Flash, Silverlight and Java Applet objects are child windows, too" - not always; Flash has a windowless mode (when the wmode param is transparent or opaque) - this allows it to be properly layered with other HTML elements; whereas in window mode, it's always on top of the HTML, regardless of the element's Z-order. Silverlight likely has similar.

Comment: @JonathanLingle Interesting: child window enumeration can be done by GetWindow too, but MS says it's not reliable: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183009

Comment: @Kol: the trick with GetWindow is that the windows can move around while you're enumerating. For example, if you're on the third HWND of five, and it becomes invalid, you now have no way to navigate to the HWND that was after it. Or a window could move in the Z-order, and you could hit it twice - or not a all. That doesn't mean you can't use it - you just have to be real careful. EnumWindows takes a snapshot, so avoids all these issues.